# IIS equivalent of VirtualHost in Apache

Tags: apache, iis, virtualhost

Is there an equivalent to Apache's VirtualHost for IIS?  We want to be able to run multiple websites from one IP and address them with different DNS names.

i.e. I have

```
www.dom1.com
www.dom2.com
www.dom3.com
```

that all point to `123.123.10.1`.  Apache would just be running on port 80 and just use virtualhost to decide which site should be served.

Is this possible in Windows IIS6?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use [Host Headers in IIS](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/) - that link will lead to a nice how-to page.

Comment: Thanks Ahockley... I will have to try that tomorrow at work.  I did try something similar but was just fiddling so may have done something wrong.

Comment: That's the kiddy.  I was trying to run them on different ports thinking only one site could be on a single port.  Now I setup the host Headers on both it works.  Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

In IIS 7, you will add in Bindings on the right side Actions column, Edit Site while the desired Site is selected.
[image: How to add Virtual Hosts in IIS]

Answer (score 3):

Create a new virtual host:

iis manager --> (local computer) --> right-click Web Sites --> New --> Web Site

Check/change/add hostname information (the other hostname to recognize) on a virtual host:

iis manager --> (local computer) --> Web Sites --> right-click/properties on one of the sites --> Web Site --> Advanced --> "Multiple identities for this Web site"

Comment: To start IIS-Manager: windows => run => inetmgr.exe

Answer (score 2):

As rob_g suggested, if you already have a website running (eg. default website) you can also select 'Edit bindings' on the website and specify a hostname.