# Hosting more than one website on private machine

Tags: redirect, dns

I currently have two websites on my computer one is at the default port another is let's say at port 100 so if the IP address or my computer is 1.2.3.4 then
http://1.2.3.4 points to one site and http://1.2.3.4:100 points to another.

It works but I do not want to give the user the IP address at it might change.

I also have two domain names registered with some provider who allows me to modify "A" record of the domains.

However I could not figure out how to manage both sites at the same time. i.e how to ensure that siteone.com points at 1.2.3.4 and sitetwo.com points to 1.2.3.4:100  ? Is it possible at all ?  The "A" record seems to work only with the default port 80.

My HTTP server is Windows IIS.

Answer (score 1):

DNS only works at the IP Address level, its only concern is mapping domain names to IP Addresses, there is no way to specify a port number.

What you should be doing is pointing all of your domains to port 80, and let the server decide which site to show based on the request, this is [Name-based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) and [Host headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302968/iis-equivalent-of-virtualhost-in-apache) in IIS (I couldn't find MS docs for)

Hopefully that should point you down the right path.