# Multiple PHP symfony sites in development server

Tags: php, symfony, iis, web, server

I have many (more than 100) web sites developed, in development environment, they are all in the same web server. The development server is running php over iis.

I'm thinking of changing to symfony, but i don't know how to create the development environment.

Currently, each time we need to develop a new web site, we just create a new folder on the development server and we go to iis and create a new application pointing to that folder.
We don't create a new site because we would need to open a new port and that would become unmanageble. So on the browser we use something like http://localhost/newwebsite
When it's time to go live, we just copy the folder to the final webserver and change some variables on a config file we have.

So... what's the best way I have to run multiple symfony web sites in one web server?

Thanks

Comment: create virtual host for each of your sf project. here is the full documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: hi, i'm running iis not apache, how can i do it with iis?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302968/iis-equivalent-of-virtualhost-in-apache

Comment: if i understood that correctly that creates a new site, so you have to have a new dns or a new port open, correct?

to clarify, i can create an application in iis and point it to the symfony site, and this works, but the js and css files (assets) are not leaded because symfony is trying to load them at the root of the server, not inside this site. for php files it works...

Comment: solve using symfony config 
 --https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html

or iis virtual host configuration check this link -- http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/symfonyOnIIS